# Quasar: How to disallow unselecting tree nodes (QTree)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

Taking the example from the [Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tree#integrated-example) about integrating the [tree](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/tree) and tabs component to show tab panels based on the selected tree node.

How can it be archived to disallow unselecting?

I tried to set up a function, which does this using the `@update:selected` event:

```html
<q-tree
@update:selected="onSelected"
>
```

```js
const onSelected = (nodeId) => {
  if (nodeId === null) {
    // How to keep last node?
  }
}
```

But how could it stop the unselection, since at the point of the event the input parameter of the callback is already set to `null` and therefore no way to know what was the last selection.

Answer (score 0):

use `:model-value @update:model-value` in your case `selected`
like so:

```html
<q-tree
  :selected="selectedModel"
  @update:selected="onSelected"
>
```

```js
const onSelected = (nodeId) => {
  if (nodeId === null) return // do nothing
  // update selected model
  selectedModel.value = nodeId
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @metalsadman. When returning on `null` without doing anything, no node is selected in the tree and that's what I want to avoid, or is the suggested setup working for you—for me, it does not seem to work out.